# Overriding failure callback function in an angular service call

Tags: angularjs

I've defined a login service this way :

```
.factory('Auth', ['$http', '$location', 'sharedProperties', 'CONSTANTS', function ($http, $location, sharedProperties, CONSTANTS) {

    return {
        login: function (username, password) {
            $http.get(CONSTANTS.BASE_URL + '/auth', {
                id: username,
                mdp: password
            }).success(function (data) {
                    sharedProperties.setApiToken(data);
                    $location.path('routes');
                }
            ).error(function (data) {
                    return 'Some error message';
                }
            )
        }

    }
}])
```

In my controller, how am I supposed to get the error message if something goes wrong ?

I tried this way :

```
$scope.login = function () {

    Auth.login(
        {
            id: "testcorp",
            mdp: "companyPassword"
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
    );
}
```

But the console.log(data) instruction doesn't get called.

Thank you,

Mathieu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create promise factory and return promise to controller. Like:

```
.factory('Auth', ['$http', '$location', 'sharedProperties', 'CONSTANTS', function ($http, $location, sharedProperties, CONSTANTS) {    

    return {
        login: function (username, password) {            
            var data =  $http.get(CONSTANTS.BASE_URL + '/auth', {
                id: username,
                mdp: password
            });

             var deferred = $q.defer();
             deferred.resolve(data);
             return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

And after, from controller:

```
        Auth.login("testcorp", "companyPassword")
                    .then(function (result) {
                       $scope.data = result;                           
                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    });
```

*As Reference*

A **promise** represents a **future** value, usually a future result of an **asynchronous** operation, and allows us to define what will happen once this value becomes available, or when an error occurs.

Comment: Works like a charm, and your promise explanation is crystal clear. Thanks a lot !